# How do i remove the keyboard from firstresponder when navigating viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app with 3 View Controllers. 
The 1st one is a `UITableView` with a list of categories.
The 2nd one is another `UITableView` with a floating `UITextField`. 
The 3rd is just a `UIViewController` with a webView.

On app launch, i dont need anything special, until `TableView2`.

On `TableView2` i have a floating `UITextField` set up like so...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self setupFloatTextBox];
    [noteTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)setupFloatTextBox {
    CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    noteTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 70, screenWidth - 10, 30)];
    noteTextField.backgroundColor = Rbg2UIColor(255, 153, 51);
    [noteTextField.layer setBorderWidth:0.5f];
    [noteTextField setAlpha:1.0f];
    [noteTextField setTag:9999];
    [noteTextField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:18.0f]];
    [noteTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(postJSON:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
    [noteTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:noteTextField];
}
```

and i remove it like so

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:9999] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

my issue is, whether going back to the first TVC or going forward to my WebView, i cant get the keyboard to disappear.

ive tried tossing these into `viewWillDisappear` but no luck

```
[noteTextField resignFirstResponder];
//
[[self view] endEditing:YES];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
//
[noteTextField endEditing:YES];
//
for(id obj in self.view.subviews)
{
    [obj resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Just to understand your situation. The three view controllers are of the same type (e.g. a unique subclass of UIViewController) or they are three separate view controllers with three separate behaviors?

Comment: Views 1 and 2 are `UITableViewControllers` (think category>subcategory) and the 3rd is a `UIViewCntroller` with an webView IBOutlet

Comment: Ok, are you subclassing UITableViewController and UIViewController or you are just using primitive objects?

Comment: sorry i think i misunderstood at first, yes they are subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think you can get a more stable behavior if you create your textfield into the `viewDidLoad` method. This because `viewDidLoad` is called everytime you *create* the view controller, instead of `viewWillAppear:` that is called everytime the view will become *visible* (e.g. if you are coming back from the Notification Center). This can be a problem because you are creating a new istance of your `UITextField` everytime `viewWillAppear:` is fired, so you can expect to have duplicate `UITextField`s in your view.

Second, why are you adding the `UITextField` into `self.navigationController` if you need it only in the second view controller? You could add it into the main view of the second view controller.

**Third, and the most important,** your code doesn't work because the `endEditing` method should be called from the view that is containing the `UITextField`. In your case, you are adding the textfield in `self.navigationController.view`, that is above `self.view` in your view hierarchy, so calling `[self.view endEditing:YES]` will do nothing. Instead, you can try to use `[self.navigationController.view endEditing:YES]` or, better, `[textField resignFirstResponder]`.

Comment: the reason i put my code in viewwillappear rather than didload was because i needed the textfield to reappear if i went to the 3rd VC and back to the second. navigating to previous view controllers wont call `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You could move the textfield from `self.navigationController.view` to `self.view` and remove the `removeFromSuperview` in `viewWillAppear:`, so the textfield stays in the second view controller even if you come back from the 3rd VC to the 2nd.

Comment: since my textfield is not in the navigationController, i cant have it hover over the title area. ill deal with that with a pan gesture and make it drag-able, other than that, i don't have a stubborn keyboard =D. thanks for the insight

Comment: You're welcome! :) If you need to show your textfield in the navigation title area, you can try to set it as `self.navigationItem.titleView`